# C++ strtok - multiple use with more data buffers

Tags: c++, strtok

I have little issue with using `strtok()` function.
I am parsing two files. Firts I load file 1 into `buffer`. This file constains name of the second file I need to load. Both files are read line after line. My code looks like this:

```
char second_file_name[128] = { "" };
char * line = strtok( buffer, "\n" );
while( line != NULL )
{
  if ( line[0] = 'f' )
  {
    sscanf( line, "%*s %s", &second_file_name );
    LoadSecondFile( second_file_name );
  }
  // processing other lines, not relevant for question
  line = strtok( NULL, "\n" );
}
```

While the `LoadSecondFile(...)` function works in pretty same way, thus:

```
char * line = strtok( buffer, "\n" );
while( line != NULL )
{
  // process file data
  line = strtok( NULL, "\n" );
}
```

What my problem is, after calling the `LoadSecondFile(...)` function, the `strtok()` pointer used for parsing the first file gets "messed up". Instead of giving me line that follows the name of the second file, it gives me nothing - understand as "complete nonsense". Do I get it right that this is caused by `strtok()` pointer being shared in program, not only in function? If so, how can I "back up" the pointer of `strtok()` used for parsing first file before using it for parsing second file?

Thanks for any advice.
Cheers.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should enable compiler warnings to catch mistakes like `if (line[0] = 'f')`.

Comment: Heh I completely missed this mistake when typing the code here, thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtok` is an evil little function which maintains global state, so (as you've found) you can't tokenise two strings at the same time. On some platforms, there are less evil variants with names like `strtok_r` or `strtok_s`; but since you're writing C++ not C, why not use the C++ library?

```
ifstream first_file(first_file_name);      // no need to read into a buffer
string line;
while (getline(first_file, line)) {
    if (!line.empty() && line[0] == 'f') { // NOT =
        istringstream line_stream(line);
        string second_file_name;
        line_stream.ignore(' ');           // skip first word ("%*s")
        line_stream >> second_file_name;   // read second word ("%s")
        LoadSecondFile(second_file_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strtok_r` which allows you to have different state pointers.

Comment: I would suggest changing "can use" to "_must_ use".

Comment: You might point out that this is a Unix extension, and may or may not be available on other systems.  And it still modifies the buffer it is parsing.

Comment: @mah: No, the C++ library is also an option. That's portable (unlike `strtok_r`) and would also fix the buffer overflow vulnerability.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say I am using Windows, so strtok_r is a no-go for me. But thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Then you can try strtok_s on Windows

Comment: @MikeSeymour `strtok_s` would solve the original problem, and fix the buffer overflow.  _And_ it is standard C11 (which doesn't mean that you'll have it with your C compiler).  But it still works on the same hacky principle of `strtok`; using the C++ standard library will result in much cleaner code.

Answer (score 3):

Which is why it is constantly recommended to *not* use `strtok`
(not to mention the problems with threads).  There are many
better solutions, using the functions in the C++ standard
library.  None of which modify the text they're working on, and
none of which use hidden, static state.

Comment: Well, my app is single threaded and I don't need the text to stay as it was, I only need to read it once and process it. Can you point out any effective way to parse file line by line without using `strtok()`?

Comment: `std::find`, `std::find_if`, `std::find_first_of`, `std::search`... All of which work far better than `strtok`,  or any of its "safer" replacements.