# Creating hashtable in C++ for string manipulation

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I am trying to process content of article or any paragraph [each string]. First I will convert into words using `strtok()`.

After that I want store each word in hashtable (because I think it's only best way to process big data). While dealing with each word, I want to store occurrence of each words. And at the end I want to get words which occurring max time.

`unordered_map` stores elements with key values and allows fast retrieval of elements with key. This may be useful to me.

I am not good with C++, so want some opinions.

1. Storing entire contains in `char *ch ="content of article"` is good way to proceed or string::str? I am familiar with first one only. for 2nd I feel complex during working with functions.
2. Storing entire content(strings) into `unordered_map()`, then How can I create hashtable which contains element as words, and it's occurrence with it. And then Can I get words with max occurance?
3. Is there any other C++ function which can help me out to do what I want.

Comment: Please don't use `strtok`, it's evil. [Relevant link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18379595/583833)

Comment: If the text is big, you should try to find solution, where you don't need to read the whole text into memory before parsing it. Parsing on the fly would make it more efficient.

Comment: @Borgleader: Thanks, But do you think the implementation you linked will do same as strtok() as per my requirment?

Comment: @AdamSangala: Yes, but reading on fly from pdf or web document itself was issue for me. So right now dealing with reading frmo text in memory!

Answer (score 3):

It seems the data structure you need will need to do several operations: looking up by key (word) and string values (count) for each key. But you also want to be able to print the frequent works, in which case you needs sorting by value.

None of the standard containers handle this out of the box. Since the first operation will be happening frequently, and the second just once, you should select container that suites best for the first operation.

Both std::map and std::unordered_map would do well.

Try following:

```
std::map<std::string, int>
```

or

```
unordered_map std::map<std::string, int>
```

For printing all the works in order of frequency, you will have to copy it into another structure and then sort it. Or it in in one operation. You can copy everything into

```
std::map<int, std::string>
```

and then just print it.

Comment: I dont need to print them in order. I just need word with max occurrence. If more then 1, then all of them. So in this case Do I need to sort it? because it will take additional time.

Comment: You could do 2 passes of the final map, one to determine which is the max count, and second pass to print all the culprits. This would be definitely faster then sorting. Alternatively, you may be able to track the max count while parsing, avoiding one of the passes.

Answer (score 2):

> I want store each word in hashtable (because I think it's only best way to process big data). While dealing with each word, I want to store occurrence of each words.

Here is some pseudo C++ to get you started:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> occurrences;
while (more_words_available)
{
    std::string word = fetch_next_word();
    ++occurrences[word];
}
```

> how I print occurrence count values for each word in while?

Do you have a C++11 compiler? Then use the new foreach loop:

```
for (auto p : occurrences)
{
    std::cout << p.first << " occurred " << p.second << " times.\n";
}
```

Otherwise, use the traditional for loop with iterators:

```
for (std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it = occurrences.begin();
                                                    it != occurrences.end();
                                                    ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->first << " occurred " << it->second << " times.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how I print occurrence count values for each word in while?

Comment: Thanks, this will solve my issue i think. But here for `occurrence` I have to declare it like `typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,int> occurrences; `. When I give only string it says `candidate expects two arguments`. I have to process content of articles where count value should be fetched itself, while here we have to give it manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. working with string is always easier
2. Words can be used as keys and count as value. Retrieval based on key is fast from a unordered_map. Getting words with max count will require iterating over the whole map.
   Your problem is that you need 2 indices.
3. Consider using Boost::MultiIndex for creating 2 indices in a container.

Answer (score 1):

If your article is in file `test.txt` then you may create your map like that:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream in_file("test.txt");
    map<string,int> words;

    string tword;
    while(in_file >> tword)  //line 12
        words[tword]++;
}
```

You can also store entire content in `istringstream ss` and use it instead of `in_file` above:

```
while(ss >> twords)  //line 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (nor want) `strtok`.  If white space is the
separator for words, just reading into a string using `>>` will
do the trick; the entire input phase would be:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> counts;
std::string word;
while ( source >> word ) {
    ++ counts[word];
}
```

Depending on the requirements, you might want to do things like
converting the word to lower case before counting it, or
stripping final punctuation from it (so that `word`, `Word` and
`Word.` are all the same).

For accessing sorted by count, the simplest would be to copy the
contents of the map into an `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,
int>>` and sorting that.  (Don't forget that you can construct
a vector from two iterators.  So this is just two more lines.)

Comment: @Karimkhan In which case, you can use `std::getline`, then `std::find_if` (or `std::find_first_of`) to break the line down into words.  For really complicated cases, you can even use regular expressions.