# C++ using multiple strtok()

Tags: c++, strtok

Hello I have following text:

```
htttp://zbw.eu/stw/descriptor/17782-1> htttp://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#inScheme> htttp://zbw.eu/stw> .

htttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_2678> htttp://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#exactMatch> htttp://zbw.eu/stw/descriptor/15918-5> . #komentar k totte hlouposti
```

..and this fucntion to tokenize data, when new line occurs:

```
    bool isCorrect(char* buffer){
    char* tok;

    tok = strtok( buffer,"\n");

    while(tok != NULL){         
        bool i = isTriple(tok);

        tok = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    return true;
}
```

when I have separate token I want to tokenize it more, so **tok** is sent to function isTriple(char * token):

```
    bool isTriple(char* token){
    char* tok;

    tok = strtok(token, " ");

    while(tok != NULL){
        tok = strtok(token, " ");
    }

    return true;
}
```

In this function input token is divided into more tokens when white space occurs. In this function I want theese new tokens send to another function to multiply and create new smaller tokens..

The problem is, that when I call isTriple(), then it wont create new smaller tokens. Suddenly it freezes.

Can anynone tell me, where am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `strtok` doesn't play nicely with multiple interleaved calls. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379305/c-strtok-multiple-use-with-more-data-buffers?rq=1) for better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

On a first call, function `strtok` expects a C string as argument, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning.

So you should not use this function "simultaneously" for several input strings.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ for a detailed description.